# .Net Application stop working on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5

My application stop working when I try to run...

In event logs, it wrote :

```
Fault bucket 94696796648, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: chuki2_spd.exe
P2: 1.2.5.0
P3: 540890bf
P4: System.Management
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 537d7fab
P7: 661
P8: 15
P9: System.Management.Management
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\UserA\AppData\Local\Temp\WER57FE.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\UserA\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_chuki2_spd.exe_5ce06ddd108095aad8b0a53dcda0f871652f59_00000000_0e855df9

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: ff84ad4d-c810-11e4-8260-60029238a606
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 29626c7db602c7dc7a499ae2109091e8
```

It working very well on windows 7 with same application...

My application using Sql CE 4.0 for database in the folder AppData. Already update to SQL CE 4.0 SP1 but still get same error.

Kindly assist me how to solved on this matter.

Comment: Did you create a new project with the same code?  Windows 8.1 projects do not allow SQL CE.  If it is just a Windows Forms or WPF application, then it should still be able to work on Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you mean I cannot using SQL CE for my database? yes this is windows forms with SQL CE as database

Comment: You should be alright then if it is Windows Forms.  I was just saying Windows 8.1 applications (store apps) do not support SQL CE directly.  If you were making a Windows store app, then you would have to either have a separate service application for database access, or change to a different database server.